# Is there any way to get Cloud Build variables into Helm values?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, google-cloud-build

I have a cloudbuild file that is using `helm package {service}` command to package a chart file before deployment. My intent is to pass the $COMMIT_SHA env value from the cloudbuild file to Helm so that I can add the commit SHA to a label on the k8s deployment. The problem is that as far as I'm aware, $COMMIT_SHA is only available in the cloudbuild file. The only values that Helm has access to are in the `values.yaml` and `Chart.yaml` files.

It's possible that I'm just seriously misunderstanding something, but I'm not seeing any way forward from here. I have read through the helm and cloud build docs. They seem to imply that cloud build can build a project using environment variables, but I am not sure if there's any way to pass values from one to the other.

Comment: I hope this makes sense. It feels jargon-y

Comment: Is it possible to see an example of what your cloud-build yaml file looks like?

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusion here is that you want to achieve this on the `helm install` or `helm upgrade` command instead of doing this on `helm package`.

Without looking at your `cloudbuild.yaml` file is hard to know what your setup looks like, but I imagine you have two steps, one for packaging your templates and another one to deploy them.

Hence on the deployment step you can do something like the following to pass the `$COMMIT_SHA` to your chart:

```
helm upgrade {chart-name} {folder} --install
--set kubernetes.deployment.label=$COMMIT_SHA
-f values.yaml
```

Edit:

After knowing a bit more how your cloudbuild steps look like, it seems like what you want to achieve has to be done before you actually package your chart.

As the pipeline is downloading the template files from a central repository, which you are later on using to generate the package, then you need a step in between to add the $COMMIT_SHA as the label to your deployment.

Imagine that you have this on your `deployment.yaml` file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: <name>
  namespace: <namespace>
  labels:
    foo: placeholder
```

And then you want the label `foo` to have a value of `$COMMIT_SHA` instead of the placeholder, before running `helm package` you'll have to run something like:

`sed -i 's/placeholder/$COMMIT_SHA/g' deployment.yaml`

So with that approach, every time that the pipeline is triggered you will be generating different versions of your chart on the fly by adding the `$COMMIT_SHA`, as you were initially mentioning.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to see how much of this I am allowed to share since it isn't my repo, but it is my intent to achieve this with `helm package` if at all possible. Basically, the setup we have is that the cloubuild file copies in the template files from a central source, runs "helm package myapp", does a couple more copies, and then runs "npm install". Maybe I need to learn more about helm, but I don't think there's a "helm install" command anywhere in the process.

Comment: Okay that helped understanding what you're trying to achieve. So now judging from the process you've described, what you're trying to do is not feasible from Helm side. The `helm package` command does not take into account any variables because you're just generating a versioned package of your templates. It is when you run `helm upgrade` or `helm install` when the variables are passed down to the templates. See my edit for a possible solution, hope it helps.

Comment: Ooh, okay, that could be possible. I will see if I can make this work and update when I can get back to it.

Comment: Did that ended up working for you? @anthony

Comment: Actually a similar thing did work. You definitely got me on the right track. I got it working a few minutes ago. What I did was use echo to pass the commit id into a new "values-extra.yaml" file from the cloudbuild file. I still need to actually utilize the new information, but I think it should be available to helm now.